# Java : TreeMap sum values of all keys

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following TreeMap.

I want the sum of the values for all keys using streams.

That is 12+24 + 14 = 50

```
TreeMap<String,Double> monthlytotal = new TreeMap<String,Double>(); 
monthlytotal.put("Jan",12);
monthlytotal.put("Feb",24);
monthlytotal.put("Mar",14);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Here's a pointer: `java.util.stream.DoubleStream`

Comment: `map.values().stream().mapToDouble(x -> x).sum()`

Comment: `map.values().stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum();`, but there are plenty of online ressources and i am certain that you would have been able to find it out yourself.

Comment: Downvoted because you did not specify what exactly is unclear to you or gives you trouble. Also because there is no sign of research. Please read the requirements for asking a question, [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take to attention - you need to add 'd' char to the double value

```
TreeMap<String,Double> monthlytotal = new TreeMap<String,Double>();
        monthlytotal.put("Jan",12d);
        monthlytotal.put("Feb",24d);
        monthlytotal.put("Mar",14d);

        Double result = monthlytotal.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .mapToDouble(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .sum();
```